# Unity how to add Lists to a List?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arraylist

I've been searching for days and can't find a solution for my problem.

I have a mini quiz game with 3-4 answer options per questions, which will be fetched randomly.

I'm getting the questions and scores from a CSV, but I don't know in what structure to store it.

```
// kind of a structure I'm looking for
Questions[0] = [["Answer 1", 2]                
               ["Answer 2", 3]
               ["Answer 3", 1]];
Questions[1] = [...]


// my approach (pseudocode) 
List<Questions> _questions = new List<Questions>();
_questions.question.Add(["What's up?",1],["What's down?",3]);
...
public class Questions{
    public Dictionary<string,int> question = new Dictionary<string,int>();
}
```

Comment: Instead of a `List<Questions>` you need a `List<Question>` (singular). This should make your design clearer. In particular that class won´t need a dictionary of all the other questions. All  `Question` should no is its own text and its answer - maybe also some kind of a score, but that´s it.

Comment: what structure? one that you are comfortable with or that you understand. You could have them in databases, xml/json files, dictionaries, lists, arrays.. choice is yours

Comment: I would like to choose a random question from the list and fetch all related details.
I know how to do it in PHP with Arrays, but don't get it in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create questions and answer objects and structure them like this:

```cs
public class Question {
   // The question that is asked.
   public string question;

   // All known answers
   public List<Answer> answers = new List<Answer>();
}

public class Answer {
   // The answer text
   public string answer;

   // The score awarded for this answer.
   public int score;
}
```

Now you can read your data from where-ever you want to read it and put it into these objects. Here is how you would create these objects manually:

```cs
var question = new Question { question  = "What is the color of the sky", answers = { 
    new Answer { answer = "It is blue", score = 1},
    new Answer { answer = "It is yellow", score = 0} 
    } 
};
```

This way you have the question and all its answers in a nice structure together for processing.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty close to what I'm looking for, but it throws me an error.

**"Assets/Quiz.cs(11,17): error CS1061: 'Answer[]' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'Answer[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**

Comment: Ow, yes I just typed this from the top of my head. You could try a List<Answer> instead of an Answer[]. I modified the code above.